# Grunt - Compress and Include assets with timestamp

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs

I've spent the whole day trying to figure out how to start with Grunt, but all the documentation I was able to find (on GitHub) specifies options and nothing else.

I'm searching for a more user-friendly documentation/how-to since I'm new to Grunt itself.

I'd like to automatize the process of minification of several .css files and include them inside my template within a placeholder defined as

```
<!-- styles -->

<!-- /styles -->
```

and

```
<!-- js -->

<!-- /js -->
```

What Grunt should do is:

- look inside my css directory
- compress files in one "main.css" and "main.js" app
- open up the html template (it would be great if it doesn't require a tmp version, but instead be able to update the same html file) and write there the final `<link>` and `<script>` tags linking to the created file appending a timestamp (for cache busting)

It seems to me like a common approach, but I'm not able to find anything ready out there.

I looked at "grunt-contrib-cssmin", "cartero", "grunt-includes", "grunt-include-replace", "grunt-usemin" and tons of alternatives... but none seems to integrate all requirements and I'm not able to make them work togheter to get what I want to.

Answer (score 11):

You're on the right track here. `grunt-usemin` will handle most of what you're looking for but it does require other packages. To get your CSS/JS minification on, you'll need to use a combo of [grunt-contrib-cssmin](https://github.com/gruntjs/) (for CSS), grunt-contrib-uglify (for JS), and while we're making our way through cool grunt packages, I'd recommend using [grunt-rev](https://github.com/cbas/grunt-rev) for cache breaking.

To get your scripts working as intended, check out the [useminPrepare task](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin#the-useminprepare-task). This will let you wrap your CSS and JS files then run tasks against them. For example, a project of mine uses a bunch of goodies from Bower so I have the following in my footer.html:

```
    <!-- build:js js/scripts.min.js -->
    <script src="./bower_components/zepto/zepto.js"></script>
    <script src="./bower_components/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="./bower_components/eventEmitter/EventEmitter.js"></script>
    <script src="./bower_components/eventie/eventie.js"></script>
    <script src="./bower_components/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.js"></script>
    <script src="./bower_components/spin.js/spin.js"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/lib/zepto.touch.module.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

Upon running, `useminPrepare` will "collect" all of these and make a configuration object that can then be used for compression/minification. My task looks like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('produce',[
  'clean:main',      // clean out the /dist directory if it exists
  'copy',            // copy files to /dist
  'useminPrepare',   // prepare an object of files that will be passed to concat and/or uglify
  'concat',          // concatenate assets
  'uglify',          // minify assets
  'usemin',          // use the minified version of these files in my html
  'compass:produce', // run production version of compass
  'clean:post'       // cleanup junk
]);
```

If you really wanted to use timestamps, you could look into adding it to the `<!-- build -->` comment but I'm not entirely sure it works (I haven't tested). One of the maintainers of Yeoman/grunt-usemin, Addy Osmani, recommends just using grunt-rev: https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/104.

As for the last bullet point, I would imagine you would want to create a tmp file otherwise you'd be destructively editing your base HTML. If that's what you want to do, I bet you can, but I'd highly recommend not doing so.

Comment: @user1978591, if this answers your question, can you please accept it as an answer?